# How to wait for a command to finish executing inside a container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile, grafana

Using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.9 AS build-go
RUN go get github.com/grafana/grafana; exit 0
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana
RUN go run build.go setup
RUN go run build.go build

FROM node:8 AS build-node
COPY --from=build-go $HOME/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana .
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
CMD npm run watch
EXPOSE 3000
```

I create and image which is then used to start a container by the bash file:

```
docker run -d -P --name=grafanabuildfromsrc myimg
docker exec grafanabuildfromsrc ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server
```

`./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server` requires `npm run build` to finish building all the files once. The current script would execute it before the build is finished.

What I am wanting is that before the second command in the bash file is executed it should wait for the command inside the container to finish first. Is this possible?

*A maybe important note:* the `grafana-server` says `"Failed to detect generated javascript files in public/build` when `npm run watch` does not finish.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: In my limited experience, running a Docker image and then immediately attempting to `docker exec` something in it is unreliable at best. Maybe I should try again though. Can you do a trivial `docker run -P --name whatever someimage sh -c 'sleep 3600'; docker exec whatever sh -c 'echo success'` for a start?

Comment: I also agree that `docker exec` isn't the tool you're looking for.  In fact, since a Docker image's content is static, a "watch" type action that rebuilds on filesystem changes probably isn't what you want either.  It seems like you'd be better off reversing the order of this Dockerfile: first build the JavaScript parts, then build the final application, `COPY`ing the `dist` folder of your built front-end there.

Comment: you can use && for sequence operations that require to run if previous command suscessful. for example `./run_some_cmd && echo "previous cmd is successful`

Comment: @tripleee yes that would work.

Comment: @DavidMaze without building the files with go, how can I `npm run`? Or can I?

Comment: @hamzatuna the problem is, the previous command is successful as soon as it starts the container but what happens inside the container is none of that command's business. I need a way to check if a command is done executing inside the container so that another one could be run.

Comment: Would `npm run build` depend on a Go binary being present?  That would be unusual.

Comment: @DavidMaze How would I clone the repository to `npm run build`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extending [@AussiDan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485927/aussiedan)'s answer, I changed my Dockerfile to:

```
FROM golang:1.9 AS build-go
RUN go get github.com/grafana/grafana; exit 0
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/github.com/grafana/grafana
RUN go run build.go setup && go run build.go build

FROM node:8 AS build-node
COPY --from=build-go $HOME/go/src/github.com/grafana/grafana .
RUN npm install -g yarn && yarn install --pure-lockfile && npm run build
CMD ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server

EXPOSE 3000
```

So that the built javascript files are already in the image when I start the grafana server.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is likely to run `npm run build` before `npm run watch`

Comment: It still wont wait for it to finish no?

Comment: the previous command is successful as soon as it starts the container but what happens inside the container is none of that command's business. I need a way to check if a command is done executing inside the container so that another one could be run.

Comment: Hey! I changed `CMD npm run watch` to `CMD npm run build && ./bin/linux-amd64/grafana-server` and it works but the container takes 5 minutes to run because of the very slow `npm run build`. You can change your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Is there any way you know that `npm run build` could be sped up?

Comment: Not that I know of